# Looking for a SQL Client which will allow me to query data from two different database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently using a SQL Client called [Dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) to query data from Postgresql and MySQL database individually. But recently there is a use case, where there is a need to combine data from this two database and then write a query.

Dbeaver doesn't have this capability. So I want to know if this is a limitation in all SQL Client or just DBeaver. If the issue is with DBeaver, then which SQL Client will allow me to combine data from two different database and then write a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're open to using a scripting client instead of a GUI client, then you might look into [execsql.py](https://pypi.org/project/execsql/).  It allows you to connect to multiple databases (one on startup, others with the [CONNECT](https://execsql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metacommands.html#connect) metacommand).  You can then copy a table or view from one database to another with the [COPY](https://execsql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metacommands.html#copy) metacommand and write queries to combine the data as needed.

Disclaimer: I wrote execsql.

Comment: I don't know python proficiently, so can you recommend alternatives?

Comment: No, I don't know of another tool with those capabilities, which is part of the reason why I wrote my own.  But you don't need to know Python to use it, you just need to have Python installed so that execsql.py will run.